# Best practice of passing actions in component inside component

Tags: ember.js

I am working on passing actions in component inside component.
In the general, I am using the method like that

home.hbs:

```
{{layerOne action1="action1" action2="action2" action3="action3" action4="action4" }}
```

home.js

```
actions:{
    action1: function () {     
      //do something
    },
    action2: function () {  
      //do something    
    },
    action3: function () {   
      //do something   
    },
    action4: function () {  
      //do something   
    }
}
```

layerOne.hbs

```
{{layerTwo action1="action1" action2="action2" action3="action3" action4="action4" }}
```

layerOne.js

```
actions:{
    action1: function () {   
      this.sendAction('action1');   
    },
    action2: function () {      
      this.sendAction('action2');   
    },
    action3: function () {   
      this.sendAction('action3');      
    },
    action4: function () {    
      this.sendAction('action4');     
    }
}
```

layerTwo.hbs

```
{{#paper-button onClick=(action "action1")}}Action 1{{/paper-button}}
{{#paper-button onClick=(action "action2")}}Action 2{{/paper-button}}
{{#paper-button onClick=(action "action3")}}Action 3{{/paper-button}}
{{#paper-button onClick=(action "action4")}}Action 4{{/paper-button}}
```

layerTwo.js

```
actions:{
    action1: function () {   
      this.sendAction('action1');   
    },
    action2: function () {      
      this.sendAction('action2');   
    },
    action3: function () {   
      this.sendAction('action3');      
    },
    action4: function () {    
      this.sendAction('action4');     
    }
}
```

If I add more actions, I have to config the layers' js file and hbs file one by one every time. Also the hbs will be very long. eg. `{{layerOne action1="action1" action2="action2" action3="action3" action4="action4" etc...}}`

Is there any best practice for this case? Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use *closure actions* to pass an action handler from upper layer to lower layer.

There are two different action passing mechanism in ember:

1. event passing such as `{{layerTwo action1="action1"`. (needs calling `sendActions` in each component to bubble up.)
2. closure actions such as `{{layerTwo action1=(action "action1")` (only needs passing action handler to the bottom.)

[This twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/e849c556d1c13e07fecd89fd8127c7b2?openFiles=templates.components.third-component.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.first-component.hbs) demonstrates how to use closure actions. You can see there is nothing in js files.

If you use closure actions with quotes such as `(action 'action1')` then a function in `actions` hash will be searched and passed to the bottom component.

If you use closure actions without quotes such as `(action action1)` then a function of that component will be passed to the bottom component. (The function needs to be either defined in that component or passed to that component.)

[This is a very good resource](http://miguelcamba.com/blog/2016/01/24/ember-closure-actions-in-depth/) to understand *closure actions*.

Comment: How to pass the action from home -> layerOne -> layerTwo in my example?
Just use closure actions in all the onClick?

Comment: Yes, if you don't need to modify it, just pass. As twiddle shows.